# cordova android facebook login error

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, phonegap

I m trying to login from facebook api in cordova android app using 
[this reference doc](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)

my login code is below

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
      alert('success');
      alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
      console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
    }

$('#call_fb').on('click', function (event) {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
      function loginError (error) {
        alert('fail');
        alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
        console.error(error)
      }
    );
});
```

using this code an error message is shown on device

> "given url is not allowed by the application configuration one or more of the given url is not allowed by the app settings."

error screenshot is here

[image]

Facebook settings page

[image: image2]

Facebook settings page
[image: image3]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991915/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration-using-firebaseui) SO question.

Comment: it is cordova based(hybrid) application, not a native application. Please give a solution for cordova.

Comment: After long research, found a solution. Added android platform in facebook developer colsole and it works. Thanks