# Facebook Login Error with Facebook Login SDK Android gives: "given URL is not allowed by.."

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have implemented Facebook Login SDK in my Android App, Sometimes after clicking on Login with Facebook button following error occurs:-

> **given URL is not allowed by the application configuration: one or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the app's setting. to use
>   this URL you must add a valid native platform in your app's
>   settings.**

Facebook login is worked perfectly worked when ***no Facebook app is installed*** (Then login is done by the browser), but in some devices, with the Facebook app(both Main app and Lite app) it gives above error. 
I have also implemented Google Login API also. It is perfectly working.

I need root cause of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Facebook Auth you need to add Android as a platform inside the In the Facebook Dashboard.

You have to go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

```
1. Select your app
2. Click settings
3. Enter contact email (for publishing)
4. Click on +add platform
```

And follow the steps mentioned in the accepted asnwer of this question.
[Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration using FirebaseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991915/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration-using-firebaseui)

Comment: Thanks for the Info.

Comment: Glad, i could help. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

try this ..

Steps:

1. Go to 'Basic' settings
2. Select 'Add Platform'
3. Select 'Android'
4. Put your :

Google Play Package Name

Class Name

Key Hashes

make sure you have a correct values.

[image: example]

Hope it works.